# Php counting +1 a inserted value in table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi guys i got 3 tables:

```
Propossals:  
id_propossal, date  

Articles:  
id_article, description  

Data:  
id, id_propossal, id_artigo, position
```

So the problem here is, i would like create something that counts automatically the position of the article on the table data.

Example:

```
Propossals  
-------------
1 04/06/2014  
2 05/06/2014

Articles
-------------
1 article01  
2 article02

Data
-------------
1(id) 1(id_propossal)  1(id_article) 1(position defined by user using INSERT)  
2(id) 1(id_propossal)  2(id_article) 2(position|this number calculates automatically +1)  
3(id) 1(id_propossal)  1(id_article) 3(position|this number calculates automatically +1)
```

and if i do for another propossal,

```
4(id) 2(id_propossal)  1(id_article) 1(position|goes back to 1 because is a new propossal)
```

Something like this, appreciate all the help.

Comment: You can do this in a procedure in the MySQL database but it is probably best to do it in PHP with a select before the insert or a select subquery.  You should probably include your PHP code since you tagged PHP.

Comment: Could you teach ne how to do it please.

Comment: Well I'm not going to write your code for you.  Show us what you have and maybe I or someone else can assist you.  As for your question, put in your PHP code and take away all the excess.  The question only requires the data table layout, the other tables don't matter.

Comment: Im not really good with php programation im a good web designer and currently im using dreamweaver that do all the work for me in php code like select, insert... so the code ill paste here will be kinda newbie probably all i have as code is a selected * database and show current fields nothing more :S

Comment: Possibly maybe you should be contracting this out or learn how to properly use PHP and MySQL code by taking a class or doing some more research.  Otherwise, whatever project you're working on will likely be buggy and insecure like many of the beginners who post here.  Not trying to mean, just realistic. Most beginners who post here post code for SQL that is highly susceptible to injections.  SO is more for code issues, not how to write it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Make a request on the Data table and find the max+1 position of any row with id_propossal equals with the one you want to insert.

For example if you want to insert 123 id_propossal

```
SELECT (COALESCE(MAX(number),0)+1) AS nextPosition  FROM Data WHERE id_propossal=123
```

This will return 1.

(COALESCE is used in case max returns null)

An other way is to save the last position on Propossalstable.

But, what if you want to remove rows from Data table? You will have unused positions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, already fixed it:

Used the MAX() function, selected the highest value from a propossal and add a +1 at it, and it solved my problem.

Thanks for your help.